# javascript setInterval - how to call multiple times and keeping the setInterval Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was experimenting with the below code to see if i could store the setInterval Id as value of a unique key in an associate array and then stopping the interval in the called function as below by using the unique value as key which should give me the setInterval Id as value for it:

```
    //random unique values to be used as key
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        uniqueID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
        list[i] = uniqueID;
    }

    //function that gets called by interval
    var runCount = 0;
    function timerMethod(id) {
        runCount++;
        if (runCount > 3) {
            console.log('done with interval where key was ' + id + ' and value was ' + id_array[id]);
            clearInterval(id_array[id]);
        }
    }

    //stores the key => setIntervalId combo
    var id_array = {};

    //fire the interval
    var tempId = list[0];
    id_array[tempId] = setInterval(function () {
        timerMethod(tempId);
    }, 3000);


    //fire the second bast*rd
    var tempId = list[1];
    id_array[tempId] = setInterval(function () {
        timerMethod(tempId);
    }, 3000);
```

The code doesn't work - somehow the second `tempId` i'm passing to the function doesn't get picked up and it always trying to stop the interval using the first key? any idea how this can be make to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of tempId inbetween the intervals and hence in the `timerMethod` function it is referencing the new value all the time.
This seems to work as expected:

```
//random unique values to be used as key
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    uniqueID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
    list[i] = uniqueID;
}

//function that gets called by interval
var runCount = 0;
function timerMethod(id) {
    runCount++;
    if (runCount > 3) {
        console.log('done with interval where key was ' + id + ' and value was ' + id_array[id]);
        clearInterval(id_array[id]);
    }
}

//stores the key => setIntervalId combo
var id_array = {};

//fire the interval
id_array[list[0]] = setInterval(function () {
    timerMethod(list[0]);
}, 3000);


//fire the second interval
id_array[list[1]] = setInterval(function () {
    timerMethod(list[1]);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **reinitialize** your `runcount var` like,

```
function timerMethod(id) {
    runCount++;
    if (runCount > 3) {
        console.log('done with interval where key was ' + id + ' and value was ' + id_array[id]);
        runCount = 0;// reinit for next list
        clearInterval(id_array[id]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tempId` is always equal to `list[1]` when timerMethod is called. You should use or another variable name, or list[1] directly

```
id_array[list[1]] = setInterval(function () {
        timerMethod(list[1]);
}, 3000);
```

Another way, if is not possible to use `list[i]`, is:

```
id_array[tempId] = setInterval((function (tid) {
        return function() {
             timerMethod(tid);
        }
})(tempId), 3000)
```